# Unable to update the selected boxes values in database using codeigniter php

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Hi I am creating a view where I will be displaying the list of records from database along with boxes where a user selects checkboxes and click on Activate button. In the database I have given a separate column for featured blogs once user click on activate, these id columns should be updated as 1 and rest will be as 0.

View:

```
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Featured Blogs</th>
                        <th scope="col">S.No</th>
                        <th scope="col">Blog Title</th>
                        <th scope="col">Author</th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>

                <?php if(isset($records) && is_array($records) && count($records)>0): ?>    
                <?php  $i=0;foreach($records as $r):$i++;?>     
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="<?php echo $r->blog_id;?>" 
                        <?php if ($r->featured_blogs == 1) { echo 'checked="checked"'; }else { echo 'disabled="disabled"'; }?> ></td>                           
                        <td class="align-center"><?php echo $i;?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $r->blog_title;?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $r->username;?></td>

                    </tr>

                <?php endforeach ;endif;?>

                </tbody>
            </table>
            <div class="pagination"><?php echo $links; ?></div> 
            <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>/blogs/active" class="button">Activate</a>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Controller:

```
function active()
{
    $this->blogs_model->active($this->uri->segment(3));
    $this->flash->success('<h2>Successfully Activated the record.<h2>');
    redirect('blogs');
}
```

Model:

```
function activate($blog_id)
{
    $data=array('status'=>1);
    $this->db->where(array('blog_id'=>$blog_id));
    $this->db->update('blogs',$data);
}
```

Comment: I see no question. Please take the time to go through the [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section.

Comment: @RoanFourie updated my question

Comment: Can anyone help me this out

Comment: Anyone help me these out thanks in advance

Comment: whats the error?

Comment: Unable to get all the selected ids and update the lsit in database

Comment: first dump or print_r your post to see whats being posted.

Comment: If i am activating the record individualyy it is working

Comment: How to get multiple records and update in database

Comment: any suggestions for this that will solve my problem

Comment: Please can any help me these problem

Comment: Anyone please help me this thank a lot in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
function active()
{
    $this->blogs_model->active($this->uri->segment(3));
    $this->flash->success('<h2>Successfully Activated the record.<h2>');
    redirect('blogs');
}


function active($blog_id)
{
    $data=array('status'=>1);
    $this->db->where(array('blog_id'=>$blog_id));
    $this->db->update('blogs',$data);
}
```

on your controller you called the model and it's function as `active($this->uri->segment(3))`
but in your model you called it as `function activate($blog_id)` 
you should need to change it

Comment: i Changed that but it will work only for one id it is not working for more than one id

Comment: can you explain much more please?

Comment: I will displaying all the records fetching from database along with checkbox.User can select one or more checkboxes from the list and click on active button . The checkboxes which he/she selected need to updated in database as 1 and the rest need to update as 0.